# Using the caret symbol (^) in substitutions in the vi editor

Tags: vi, editors

I'm using CentOS and I was reading about the substitution command, `s///`, in the `vi` editor. I wanted to test some of the examples I saw:

```
:%s/old/new/g     Substitutes old with new throughout the file
:.,$s/old/new/g   Substitutes old with new from the current cursor position to the end of the file
```

The above examples worked as expected for me, but the following containing the caret symbol (`^`) didn't work:

```
 :^,.s/old/new/g   Substitutes old with new from the beginning of the file to the current cursor position
```

I tried it, but it didn't work, so is caret not working or am I typing the command incorrectly?

Comment: Should be 1 instead of carat. Line numbers are the norm. $ is just short for the last line.

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson It should be `1` if the text comment was correct. It should be `-1` or just `-` if the historical meaning of `^` in addresses is to be followed.

Comment: PS we also have [vi.se]!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the `vi` editor, as well as in both `ex` and `ed` (as found on BSD systems), the `^` addresses the previous line.  This means that the command `^d` would delete the previous line, `^m.` would swap this line with the previous, and that `^,.s/old/new/g` would substitute all strings matching `old` with `new` on the previous line and on this line.

The `vim` editor, being an extended re-implementation of the original `vi` and `ex` editors, commonly installed on Linux systems under the names `vim`, `vi`, and `ex`, does not have this way of addressing the previous line, and will respond with "[E492: Not an editing command](https://vimhelp.org/message.txt.html#E492)" if you try to use it.   You may use `-` or `-1` in its place:

```
-,.s/old/new/g
```

Using `-` or `-1` in place of `^` also works in `ed`, `ex` and in `vi` on non-GNU systems.

The POSIX standard [says the following](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ed.html) about this in relation to the `ed` editor:

> Historically, `ed` accepted the `^` character as an address, in which case it was identical to the `<hyphen-minus>` character. POSIX.1-2017 does not require or prohibit this behavior.

There is a [similar wording](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html) for the `vi` and `ex` editors (`ex` is `vi`  "in line editor mode"):

> Historically, `ex` and `vi` accepted the `^` character as both an address and as a flag offset for commands. In both cases it was identical to the `-` character. POSIX.1-2017 does not require or prohibit this behavior.

Note that the text that you seem to be quoting says that `^,.` addresses all lines from the top of the file to the current line.  This is not correct.  It only addresses the previous and the current line, and only does so in "historically accurate" implementations of `vi` (and `ex` and  `ed`).  To address all lines from the start of the editing buffer to the current line, use `1,.`.

The `^`-instead-of-`1` typo could possibly come from thinking that "since `$` is the end-of-line anchor in regular expressions, and also the address of the last line in the editing buffer, `^`, being the start-of-line anchor in regular expressions, must therefore (by symmetry) be the *first* line of the editing buffer".

Just to provide another piece of trivia: The `^` address can also not be used in the GNU implementation of the `ed` editor.  As in any other implementation of `ed`, `-` or `-1` may still be used as an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

The site where you found this `vi`command is wrong.

It might be [that 1996 site](https://staff.washington.edu/rells/R110/) or one of the many other who copied/pasted these lines without double checking.

```
Using vi, the Unix Visual Editor

…

:.,$s/old/new/g   Substitutes old with new from the current
                       cursor position to the end of the file

:^,.s/old/new/g   Substitutes old with new from the beginning
                       of the file to the current cursor position

© Copyright 1996 University of Washington Computing & Communications.
```

What should have been written is:

```
:1,.s/old/new/g
```

The caret has several usages under `vi`. One of them is to tell the beginning of line in the pattern area, so `/^old/`means "old" when starting line just like `$` means end of line so `/old$/` means "old" when ending a line.

I'm sure the confusion is due to this symmetry. The author (Rick Ells) thought the caret `^` means either beginning of a file or beginning of a line just like `$` means end of a file or end of a line but the fact is it is not the case.

It also happens the caret also has a specific and different meaning when used as an address like Kusalananda pointed but IMHO it is anecdotal as I have never met anyone using this shortcut, `-1` being much more intuitive.

Comment: thanks mate , so the caret ^ is not working right , and it is easier to set the first line number "1" instead right ?!

Comment: @user447343, no. The caret is working exactly as it should, and it's not applicable here. It is the documentation that is wrong telling you that you can use it in an address range instead of `1`

Comment: @roaima thanks a lot  .